# Convert JSONB Keys to Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

I have a user table `users`  containing `id` , `name` and `information` of type jsonb

User Table

| id | name | information |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Alice | {"1":"Google","2":"1991-02-08"} |
| 1002 | Bob | {"1":"StackOverflow","3":"www.google.com"} |

I have another Table having all the profile fields values named `ProfileFields`

| profilefieldid | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Company |
| 2 | DateOfBirth |
| 3 | ProfileLink |

The `information` jsonb column can only have keys present in the ProfileField Table.

You can expect the data is coming from a real world and the profile field will be updating.

I would like to output export this table in the format of

| id | name | Company | DateOfBirth | ProfileLink |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Alice | Google | 1991-02-08 |  |
| 1002 | Bob | StackOverflow |  | [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) |

**My Trails :-**
I was able to map profilefieldid with its respective values

```
SELECT
id ,
name ,
(SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT((SELECT "title" FROM "profile_fields" WHERE CAST("key" AS INTEGER)="id"),':',REPLACE("value",'"','')),',') FROM JSONB_EACH_TEXT("profile_fields")) "information"
FROM "users" ORDER BY "id";
```

I tried to use json_to record() but since the profilefield can have dynamic keys i was not able to come up with a solution because in the AS block i need to specify the columns in advance.

I sometimes encounter errors in Select Statement as Subquery returning more than 1 column.

Any suggestions and Solutions are greatly appreciated and welcomed.

Let me know if i need to improve my db structure , like its not in 2nd NormalForm or not well structured like that. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can make this dynamic. A fundamental restriction of the SQL language is, that the number, names and data type of all columns of a query must be known before the database starts retrieving data.

What you can do though is to create a stored procedure that generates a view with the needed columns:

```
create or replace procedure create_user_info_view()
as
$$
declare
  l_columns text;
begin
  
  select string_agg(concat('u.information ->> ', quote_literal(profilefield_id), ' as ', quote_ident(value)), ', ')
    into l_columns
  from profile_fields;
  
  execute 'drop view if exists users_view cascade';
  execute 'create view users_view as select u.id, u.name, '||l_columns||' from users u';
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

After the procedure is executed, you can run `select * from users_view` and see all profile keys as columns.

If you want, you can create a trigger on the table `profile_fields` that re-creates the view each time the table is changed.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/VRJ-Zhn3)

Comment: Sry for late doubts i have ended up getting duplicate Column names. The ProfileFields table have different id but same title. How can i handle that ?